# How to reload my google chart based on button click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, charts

This is my code used to display chart and display number of votes. It was working perfectly.

In this code when I click refresh button votes will be update without refreshing page. How can I do this?

```
<div id="barchart" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;margin-top:0px;"></div>

<button>Refresh</button>

<?php
$q_id = $row['q_id'];
include "connection.php";
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM votes where q_id='$q_id'");
$count1 = mysql_num_rows($sql1);

$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM votes where q_id='$q_id' and answer='Yes'");
$count2 = mysql_num_rows($sql2);

$sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM votes where q_id='$q_id' and answer='No'");
$count3 = mysql_num_rows($sql3);
?>   

<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
google.setOnLoadCallback(render_applicant_sources);

function drawChart() {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Task');
    dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
    // A column for custom tooltip content
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
    dataTable.addRows([
      ['<?php echo "Yes"; echo " "; echo ' ('.$count2.' '.$vname1.')'; ?>',    <?php echo $count2; ?> ,'<?php echo "Yes"; ?>'],
      ['<?php echo "No"; echo " "; echo ' ('.$count3.' '.$vname2.')'; ?>',     <?php echo $count3; ?>,'<?php echo "No"; ?>']
    ]);

var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('barchart'));

var options = {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    pieSliceText:'none',
    chartArea: {top: 10},
    titleTextStyle: {bold: false},
    enableInteractivity: false,
    legend: {position: 'labeled',textStyle: {color: '#000',fontSize:13}},
    height:250,
    fontName:"'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif",
     tooltip: {
        text: 'value'
    }
};
chart.draw(dataTable, options);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Most common way to accomplish this:

- Instead of using inline PHP to load your data from your database, have a *service*, a dedicated URL, which (using the same PHP) returns this data (preferably) in JSON format. Then make an AJAX JavaScript call to get this data when you load the page and store it in some JavaScript data structure.
- Instead of using inline PHP to insert this data in your chart, use the aforementioned JavaScript data instead

If you acquire your data this way, your refresh button can simply do these steps again: get new data from your service URL and redraw the chart based on that. This kind of design is sometimes called Service Oriented Architecture (SOA).